# Hilbert irreducibility theorem and Galois groups

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand why Hilbert irreducibility theorem implies the Galois group of a random polynomial is $S_n$ 100% of the time and found [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117820/how-to-apply-hilberts-irreducibilty-theorem). I am having trouble understanding the argument given in the answer.

> [...] you have to take a minimal polynomial $g(t,X)$ of a primitive element of the splitting field of $f(t,X)$ over $K(t)$. Then $g(a,X)$ is irreducible for infinitely many $a\in K$ by Hilbert's irreducibility theorem, and $g(a,X)$ and $g(t,X)$ have the same Galois group over  $K$ and $K(t)$, respectively.

I get that $f(t, X)$ has Galois group $S_n$ and so we can find a minimal polynomial $g(t, X)$ with Galois group $S_n$ as well. Why does the fact that $g$ is a minimal polynomial imply that any irreducible specializations of $g$ to $t=a$ also has Galois group $S_n$? And how can we bring this back to specializations of $f$--does it follow that $f(a, X)$ also has Galois group $S_n$?

Comment: $g$ has degree $n!$ and its specialization $g_a$ at $a$ is irreducible for infinitely many $a$. For those $a$, $g_a$ has degree $n!$, it is irreducible, and with $c$ one of its roots, all the others are rational functions in $c$, and $S_n$ acts transitively on those root. This impllies that $K(c)/K$ is Galois with $Gal(K(a)/K)=S_n$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Could you please explain why $f(c, X)$ has the same splitting field $K(a)$?